# templateUrl Angular 4 and asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, angular2-template-loader

I'm trying to load `templateUrl` parameter from Angular component in MVC application and get this error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

How could I use `templateUrl` parameter in `app.component.ts`?

Comment: Can that URL be loaded when the application gets compiled?

Comment: yes when compiled the application in VStudio don`t get any error the issue appear in console log in browser

Comment: Can you put some code example in your question ?